# Is there a traditional modal dialog in JqueryMobile 1.0 library (not a plugin)

Tags: jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

I was able to use the dialog, but need a typical modal dialog which has the current page in the background and the dialog is on top of the current screen.

The default dialog seems to take the whole screen and the current page is gone with the mobile.changepage call to display the dialog. Even if there was a way to adjust the height and width of the dialog it still wont serve the purpose since the previous page is already gone.

I believe there are some plugins, but I'm wondering if there is one which comes with the default library (1.0 final version) or if there is a way to create one using the library without a lot of coding if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment,this support is not there in JQM 1.0 library.But this feature is going to be there in the 1.2 version as per the JQM blog http://jquerymobile.com/blog/ . In the meanwhile you can check http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html to see a rough preview.May be you can check the source code and see if it is possible to do so in JQM 1.0

Hope that helps.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks, let me check the time lines for 1.2 release if i can wait.